# Facebook: how to setup the Auth Dialog Button to Display "Okay, Watch Video" instead of "Go to App"

Tags: facebook, authentication, button, dialog

Facebook: how to setup the Auth Dialog Button to Display "Okay, Watch Video" instead of "Go to App" ?

other similar apps like socialcam, dailymotion, metacafe, viddy ... shows an auth dialog with the wording "Okay, watch video".

[image]